# Out of memory error when calling a MATLAB JA Builder compiled component

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm having a strange problem with calling a MATLAB JA Builder compiled code in Java. Details are as follows:

1. The code does a `load()` on a large .mat file
2. If the mat file was opened in MATLAB (by importing the .mat), everything works fine and takes up ~900MB of memory
3. If the code is called from an Java app (which simply imports the function built by JA Builder), I get out of memory from the MATLAB script
4. I have tried setting Xmx really high, but that doesn't seem to do anything at all
5. What is weirder, is that if the java program is run through the Eclipse debugger, it can use up to 900MB of ram and the `load()` function succeeds

Does anyone know what could be happening?

---

I have attached a part of the stack trace:

```
??? Error using ==> load
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
file C:\Users\HiME\AppData\Local\MathWorks\mcr_cache_v78\fileProcesso_39586D5669D9A968B2CD5231A43620E4\fileProcesso\getHeaders.m,name getHeaders,line at 8.
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Error using ==> load
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.Error in =>getHeaders.m at 8
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this with smaller MAT files? What is the largest you can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting -Xmx *lower* instead.

In a regular Matlab process, the memory is split between the Java heap used for Java objects, and the other memory available to Matlab M data structures like the result of that load. Making the Java heap bigger adjusts that dividing line, taking memory away from native code and Matlab's GC, and giving it to Java. Basically, the Java heap and Matlab heap are in competition for memory. The JVM running inside a JA Builder library probably works the same way.

Check the heap size you're running with under Eclipse and compare it to how your Java app is normally running, and try reducing the Java heap size to reserve more memory for the Matlab heap.

Comment: Interesting. I have tried setting -Xmx to anything from 500M to 20M with no effect. Is there anything else you can think of?

Thanks

Comment: Try calling `feature memstats` at the beginning of your M-code. That will make Matlab dump out some memory diagnostics showing how much memory it has available, and you can see more directly what effect the Java startup parameters and contexts have on memory for Matlab.